# Custom scopes on many to many pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have a many to many relation between User and Task. The pivot table acts as an "Inbox" view on the user's tasks and is defined as a custom model, which is nice...

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'inbox_messages')
                        ->withPivot('read', 'pinned', 'suggested', 'last_viewed_at')
                        ->withTimestamps()
                        ->using(Inbox::class)
                        ->as('inbox');
}
```

However, when I want to query Tasks, I feel kinda limited when querying the pivot table...

For example, I want to query for Tasks that were viewed today and are pinned...

```
$tasks = Auth::user()->tasks()
                    ->wherePivot('pinned', true)
                    ->wherePivot('last_viewed_at', Carbon::today)
                    ->get();
```

But I actually want to be able to write it as follows, **reusing the local scopes** I have already defined on my Inbox pivot model...

```
$tasks = Auth::user()->tasks()
                    ->wherePivotPinned()
                    ->wherePivotViewedToday()
                    ->get();
```

Even better would be something like this, using the **pivot accessor** in the Builder method...

```
$tasks = Auth::user()->tasks()
                    ->whereInboxPinned()
                    ->whereInboxViewedToday()
                    ->get();
```

Maybe it's already possible but undocumented?

If not, how could this functionality be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a pretty way of doing it with your syntax.

`Auth::user()->tasks()` returns an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany` class.

```
/**
 * Define a many-to-many relationship.
 * ...
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null, $relatedPivotKey = null,
                              $parentKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null)
{
    ...

    return $this->newBelongsToMany(
        $instance->newQuery(), $this, $table, $foreignPivotKey,
        $relatedPivotKey, $parentKey ?: $this->getKeyName(),
        $relatedKey ?: $instance->getKeyName(), $relation
    );
}


/**
 * Instantiate a new BelongsToMany relationship.
 * ...
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
protected function newBelongsToMany(Builder $query, Model $parent, $table, $foreignPivotKey, $relatedPivotKey,
                                    $parentKey, $relatedKey, $relationName = null)
{
    return new BelongsToMany($query, $parent, $table, $foreignPivotKey, $relatedPivotKey, $parentKey, $relatedKey, $relationName);
}
```

Since these methods are available in your model, you could override the `newBelongsToMany()` function return a custom `BelongsToMany` class that extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany` where you could add the methods.

... But at that point just how far are you willing to go just for some syntactic sugar? The code already looks pretty clear.

Comment: Fair point about the syntactic sugar, tnx! If you would have an idea on where to start implementing it, though, please share :) I'll have a look for myself as well...

Comment: The other way to do this would be to make a separate pinnedTasksThatWereViewedToday() with all the conditions but again, I think that's going too far.